# PyPDF2.errors.PdfReadError: PDF starts with '♣▬', but '%PDF-' expected

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a folder containing a lot of sub-folders, with PDF files inside. It's a real mess to find information in these files, so I'm making a program to parse these folders and files, searching for a keyword in the PDF files, and returning the names of the PDF files containing the keyword.

And it's working. Almost, actually.

I have this error: `PyPDF2.errors.PdfReadError: PDF starts with '♣▬', but '%PDF-' expected` when my program reaches some folders (hard to know which one exactly). From my point of view, all the PDF files in my folders are the same, so I don't understand why my program works with some files and doesn't work with others.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: Why is it "hard to know which one exactly"???  Put in a `print()`, so you can tell what file is triggering this non-PDF error.

Comment: Sounds like one of your pdfs is not actually pdf. Find out which one and examine that in a regular pdf viewer.

Comment: With the help of Jasonharper (sorry I didn't think of it before), I found the problematic files. These are PDF in version 1.5, while the working ones are in 1.4. I tried to convert these pdfs with an online converter, but that doesn't seem to have solved the problem, because I still have the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**disclaimer**: I am the author of `borb`, the library mentioned in this answer

PDF documents caught in the wild will sometimes start with non-pdf bytes (a header that is not really part of the PDF spec). This can cause all kinds of problems.

PDF will (internally) keep track of all the byte offsets of objects in the file (e.g. "object 10 starts at byte 10202"). This header makes it harder to know where an object starts.

- Do we start counting at the start of the file?
- Or at the start of where the file behaves like a PDF?

If you just want to extract text from a PDF (to be able to check it for content and keywords), you can try to use `borb`.

`borb` will look for the start of the PDF within the first 1MB of the file (thus potentially ignoring your faulty header). If this turns out to corrupt the XREF (cross reference table, containing all byte addresses of objects) it will simply build a new one.

This is an example of how to extract text from a PDF using `borb`:

```py
import typing
from borb.pdf.document.document import Document
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit.text.simple_text_extraction import SimpleTextExtraction


def main():

    # read the Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    l: SimpleTextExtraction = SimpleTextExtraction()
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l])

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # print the text on the first Page
    print(l.get_text_for_page(0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can find more examples in the [examples repository](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples).

Comment: After adapting your code to my situation, all my files can be read without problem. Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 7):

**`PdfFileReader` is deprecated. Use `PdfReader` instead! ([source](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/migration-1-to-2.html#classes))**

PdfFileReader has a `strict` attribute. Use it:

```
reader = PdfFileReader("example.pdf", strict=False)
```

PdfReader is the same as PdfFileReader, but by default it has `strict=False`. Most people want `strict=False`. In the next major release, I will remove PdfFileReader from PyPDF2 in favor of PdfReader.

If you're still getting issues, please open an issue on Github - but only if you can share a pdf+code that caused the issue: https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2

Comment: Thanks kind of worked well for some but for some got this error "PyPDF2.errors.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found"

Comment: Can you open that file in any PDF viewer?

Comment: yes, but still this error thanks for your time

Comment: @DS_ShraShetty Without more information I cannot help you. My guess is that you try to open a broken PDF file - which is expected not to work

Answer (score 0):

doesn't crawl pdf or damages it while doing it. Use this:

```
response = 

requests.get("your link")
pdf_io_bytes = io.BytesIO(response.content)
text_list = []
pdf = pypdf.PdfReader(pdf_io_bytes)

num_pages = len(pdf.pages)

for page in range(num_pages):
    page_text = pdf.pages[page].extract_text()
    text_list.append(page_text)
text = "\n".join(text_list)
```